# Cannot preview IBDesignable custom component on Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm trying to make a custom UI component which can be previewed on Interface Builder.  First I tried to code by myself but I couldn't make it (it works on the built app but cannot be previewed on IB.)

Of course I suspected my code's wrong so I grabbed the project from the tutorial which I made reference to.

https://cheesecakelabs.com/blog/building-custom-ui-controls-xcodes-interface-builder/

But the result is just showing a rectangle, instead of showing two buttons in the custom component.
I built the project but it didn't take effect to the preview.

The reason I think is one of the below, but basically I have no clue about its further detail. Does anybody have any idea?

1. There was some changes in InterfaceBuilder since the tutorial of
   above link was written(Sep 2017)
2. The tutorial is wrong from the beginning
3. I have a wrong configuration in XCode/InterfaceBuilder
4. I am misunderstanding the purpose of the above tutorial, and buttons on that custom component cannot be previewed in any ways

Or if anybody has an experience of success/fail in previewing this custom component please let me know as well.

Thanks!

Comment: please share some code. I suspect that the two buttons you are expecting to see are not drawn in the IB lifecycle but are drawn in a normal UIViewController lifecycle.

Comment: The code is the exact one from the above link.
https://github.com/ricardo0100/IBComponents

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the pre-defined Title property of the buttons in your `AwesomeView.xib` are overriding the user-defined property when the `@IBDesignable` control is rendered in IB.

Not sure if this is by design or a bug (I'm leaning toward it being a bug).

To get around it, you can:

open `AwesomeView.xib` and delete the "Button 1" and "Button 2" titles

or

add this line at the end of `initNib()`:

```
button1.setTitle("", for: .normal)
```

Initially, you will only see blank buttons... but setting the `button1Title` in IB should work.

Comment: Didn't work... It's not only the title text but the button itself is not shown in my place.

Comment: When you have your Storyboard open, make sure you have `Editor -> Automatically Refresh Views` checked. You may also need to select `Editor -> Refresh All Views`. When you do so, do you get any errors or warnings?

Comment: Thanks, but both didn't work.  And I didn't get any errors either.

Comment: @TakeshiYokemura - not sure what the problem is then... I just downloaded a fresh copy of that `IBComponents` GitHub repo, opened it in Xcode 9, opened Main.storyboard... and after a couple seconds, I see the 2 buttons in the custom view.

Comment: Thanks. That's a valuable info.  It means that something is wrong with my XCode environment.